# Use PHP to redirect to anchor for modal window

Tags: php, html, css

I am new to modal overlays and have a modal php as follows:

```
<div id="MessageBox" class="modalMessageBox">
<?php start-session() ?>
    <div>
        <a title="Close" class="close" href="#close" >X</a>
        <h2><?php $_SESSION['MessageBox_Title']; ?></h2>
        <br><br>
        <p><?php $_SESSION['MessageBox_Error']; ?></p>
        <br><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="#openLogin">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="index.php">no</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I need to pass control after inserting data to the data base to indicate the insert was successful. I'm able to pass control to a modal window from an 'a' tag on the href attribute (e.g. Here), but requires user intervention. Here's what I want to do:

```
<pre><?php
    session_start();
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: developer
 * Date: 4/18/14
 * Time: 10:46 AM
 */
include_once './dha_datamgr.php';
include_once './regform.php';
/* Load Registration Record */
if (SubmitRegistration()) {
/* enter server side code to redirect to #MessageBox if everything went okay. */
}else{
$hdr = 'location:../registration.php';
header($hdr);
}
?>
```

Here is the site I am using to help model my modal dialogs (http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/).

Comment: how are you submitting the form ?

Comment: Here's the tag in the form file "registration.php"

                            <form class="registrationForm" name="regForm" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SESSION['FORM']['ACTION'];?>">
where the session variable is  'ACTION' => 'php/ProcessRegistration.php',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you would like to display an error dialog message if the submitted registration is failed.

You should understand that PHP is a server side programming and javascript is client side programming. From what you would like to create is a client side event after submitting a registration form a popup an error dialog will display correct?

I would suggest to use a [jQuery.post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) when submitting the form and get the php server respond if it failed to display the error message in a dialog box.

Comment: So what you are saying is I can redirect to a web page with server side code, but cannot direct to a modal window (anchor tag) using server side code?

Comment: Ivan, I didn't answer your question, yes, I am trying to show a modal dialog overlay using CSS3. My Other option is to using 'Header' to direct to a HTML page with a box indicating the registration has been accepted and they can now login or return to home page.

Comment: Ic.. I get your point. Creating an interactive dialog box takes time understanding what is ajax to accomplish what your asking.

Comment: Ivan, thanks for directing me to jQuery. This was the correct approach and appears to be working okay. I'm running into one issue and if you have time to look at my most recent question, that would be much appreciated.